# Clean, pythonic way for concurrent data loaders?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, io, multiprocessing

**Python 3**

I would like to know what a really clean, pythonic concurrent data loader should look like. I need this approach for a project of mine that does heavy computations on data that is too big to entirely fit into memory. Hence, I implemented data loaders that should run concurrently and store data in a queue, so that the main process can work while (in the mean time) the next data is being loaded & prepared. Of course, the queue should block when it is empty (main process trying to consume more items -> queue should wait for new data) or full (worker process should wait until main process consumes data out of the queue to prevent out-of-memory errors).

I have written a class to fulfill this need using Python's `multiprocessing` module (`multiprocessing.Queue` and `multiprocessing.Process`). The crucial parts of the class are implemented as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from itertools import cycle    

class ConcurrentLoader:
    def __init__(path_to_data, queue_size, batch_size):
        self._batch_size
        self._path = path_to_data
        filenames = ... # filenames for path 'path_to_data',
                        # get loaded using glob
        self._files = cycle()
        self._q = mp.Queue(queue_size)
        ...
        self._worker = mp.Process(target=self._worker_func, daemon=True)
        self._worker.start() # only started, never stopped

    def _worker_func(self):
        while True:
            buffer = list()
            for i in range(batch_size):
                f = next(self._files)
                ... # load f and do some pre-processing with NumPy
                ... # add it to buffer
            self._q.put(np.array(buffer).astype(np.float32))

    def get_batch_data(self):
        self._q.get()
```

The class has some more methods, but they are all for "convenience functionality". For example, it counts in a dict how often each file was loaded, how often the whole data set was loaded and so on, but these are rather easy to implement in Python and do not waste much computation time (sets, dicts, ...).

The data part itself on the other hand, due to I/O and pre-processing, can even take seconds. That is the reason why I want this to happen concurrently.

`ConcurrentLoader` should:

- block main process: if `get_batch_data` is called, but queue is empty
- block worker process: if queue is full, to prevent out-of-memory errors and prevent `while True` from wasting resources
- be "transparent" to any class that uses `ConcurrentLoader`: they should just supply the path to the data and use `get_batch_data` without noticing that this actually works concurrently ("hassle free usage")
- terminate its worker when main process dies to free resources again

Considering these goals (have I forgotten anything?) what should I do to enhance the current implementation? Is it thread/dead-lock safe? Is there a more "pythonic" way of implementation? Can I get it more clean? Does waste resources somehow?

Any class that uses `ConcurrentLoader` would roughly follow this setup:

```
class Foo:
    ...

    def do_something(self):
        ...
        data1 = ConcurrentLoader("path/to/data1", 64, 8)
        data2 = ConcurrentLoader("path/to/data2", 256, 16)
        ...
        sample1 = data1.get_batch_data()
        sample2 = data2.get_batch_data()
        ... # heavy computations with data contained in 'sample1' & 'sample2'
            # go *here*
```

Please either point out mistakes of any kind in order to improve my approach or supply an own, cleaner, more pythonic approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Blocking when a `multiprocessing.Queue` is empty/full and
  `get()`/`put()` is called on it happens automatically.
- This behavior is transparent to calling functions.
- Use `self._worker.daemon = True` before `self._worker.start()` so the worker(s) will automatically be killed when main process exits